# How to input a JSON object as a parameter into Controller methods in C#

Tags: c#, json, controller

Below is my Controller Class:

```
using Pay.Models;
using System.Web.Http;
using Pay.General;

namespace Pay.Controllers
{
    [RoutePrefix("Account")]
    public class AccountsController : ApiController     
    {

        [Route("Login")]
        [HttpPost]   
        public UserSession Login([FromBody]LoginUser loginUser)
        {
            if (loginUser.email != null && loginUser.password !=null && loginUser.token !=null) { }
            byte[] mSessionID = new Session().getmSessionID();
            return new UserSession
            {
                SessionID = mSessionID
            };
        }
    }
}
```

The Model class LoginUser is

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Pay.Models
{
    public class LoginUser
    {
        public string email { get; set; }
        public string password { get; set; }
        public byte[] token { get; set; }
    }
}
```

But When I call the Login function, the LoginUser object is set to null.
Please advise on how to set JSON objects into Controller class.

Comment: try to change FromBody to FromURI

Comment: can you share your caller method ?

Comment: refer this link it might help to you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5022958/passing-dynamic-json-object-to-c-sharp-mvc-controller

Comment: I am able to input values from JSON object into Model class(LoginUSer.java) except for Token.. Token remains as null, both other values are getting mapped to the LoginUSer class

Comment: My colleague researched well, and she was able to find a proper link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got help from my colleague, and she was able to find a proper link.

https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2013/dec/13/accepting-raw-request-body-content-with-aspnet-web-api....

The code changes I made to fix the issue are

public async Task Login()
        {
            string input = await Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();            dynamic data = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(input); 
        }

(input -returns as a string in in JSON  format)
(data - returns the JSON Object)