# C#/MVC Web app - Dynamic object from JSON

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I've been looking over the Internet but didn't find something relate to my problem.

I have visual studio 2017. Working in 4.6.1 .NET framework. The application is an asp.net MVC 4 application (standard).

I have a controler Dataset :

```
public class DatasetController : Controller
{
    [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Push(dynamic data)
    {
        try
        {
            //here data has a value of {object} and is object typed
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
        }
        return Json(null);
    }
}
```

The client can push any kind of data he wants. I will handle the structure from the dynamic object.
I tried to switch to IDictionary type. But sub object still get the {object} value thing...

Here is the JSON sent (with content type as application/json) through Postman.

```
{
  data: {
    ApplicationName: "test",
    TestObject: {
      Name:"TestObject",
      TestInt: 42
    }
  }
}
```

My problem is I don't know how to deal with this kind of object. How can I retrieve information from ? I can't call :

```
var test = data.ApplicationName
```

It will throw a RuntimeBinderException with message "object" does not contain a definition for ApplicationName.

With strongly typed variables or interfaces I never ran into such a problem (bassically obvious...).

Please tell me if my post lack of information.

Thank you for your time.

EDIT : Added precisions about my problem and the Exception I could get trying to work with this object

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/a/17050505/2810015 if it solved your problem.

Comment: I works. Answering my question quoting your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Nimish comment on the question. Here is a post answering my problem :
[Passing dynamic json object to C# MVC controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5022958/passing-dynamic-json-object-to-c-sharp-mvc-controller/17050505#17050505)

The problem is coming from the Json.Net serializer not used by default by the Controller serializer. So we create value provider

```
public sealed class JsonDotNetValueProviderFactory : ValueProviderFactory
{
    public override IValueProvider GetValueProvider(ControllerContext controllerContext)
    {
        if (controllerContext == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("controllerContext");

        if (!controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.ContentType.StartsWith("application/json", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            return null;

        var reader = new StreamReader(controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.InputStream);
        var bodyText = reader.ReadToEnd();

        return String.IsNullOrEmpty(bodyText) ? null : new DictionaryValueProvider<object>(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(bodyText, new ExpandoObjectConverter()), CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
    }
}
```

Then creating a Wrapper in order to strongly type the parameter :

```
public class JsonDynamicWrapper
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Dynamic json obj will be in payload.
    /// 
    /// Send to server like:
    /// 
    /// { payload: data }
    /// </summary>
    public dynamic payload { get; set; }
}
```

Then updating the Push method :

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
public JsonResult Push(JsonDynamicWrapper data)
{
    try
    {
        var test = data.payload.ApplicationName;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
    }
    return Json(null);
}
```