# Dynamic parameters in controller ASP.NET MVC C#

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, model, custom-model-binder

I'm sending a json in the view with an ajax request and need to use it in the controller. But this json has dynamic parameters that means somethings it could have 10 or more properties so I cannot define a model. How can I get access to the properties in the controller?

Ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
          url: 'SaveSub',
          type: 'POST',
          contentType: 'application/json',
          data: JSON.stringify(data),                        
          error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
              alert('Error.');
          }
});
```

Json ex1:

```
"{"ID":2,"WareCost":"Cost","Driver":6,"Capri": 5622.599999999999, "Polo":14993.6, "Depor":937.1,"PorCost":62}"
```

Json ex2:

```
"{"ID":2,"WareCost":"Cost","Driver":6, "Depor":937.1,"Sands":937.1,"Leg": 5622.599999, "Polo":14993.6, "Depor":937.1,"PorCost":80}"
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult SaveSub(object model) 
{
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing dynamic json object to C# MVC controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5022958/passing-dynamic-json-object-to-c-sharp-mvc-controller)

Comment: You can also post the json contents as string to the action method and json deserialize the string to Dictionary.